# Segmentation fault when using Used-defined conversion operator

Tags: c++, operators

I have implemented the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
    public:
        int a;

        virtual ~A()
        {
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        int b;

        virtual ~B()
        {
        }
};

class E : public B
{
    public:
        ~E()
        {
        }
};

class D
{
public:
    operator std::shared_ptr<A>()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<A>();
        pa->a = this->y;
        return pa;
    }

    operator std::shared_ptr<B>()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> pb = std::make_shared<B>();

        pb = *this;
        (std::static_pointer_cast<B>(pb))->b = this->x;
        return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(pb);
    }

    virtual ~D()
    {
    }

    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.x = 6;
    d.y = 7;
    std::shared_ptr<E> pE = std::make_shared<E>();
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = pE;

    std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(pa);
    pB = d;
    std::cout << "a " << pB->a << "b " << pB->b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I try to do is to convert the instance of class `D`, `d`, in a instance of shared pointer `B` which is derived from class `A`.

The `B` inherits the class `A`, and `E` inherits the class `B`.

When the program terminates, the program crashes in the destructor of class `A`.

I used GDB and see that `this` is NULL.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Doing the following change                                               
 (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(pb))->b = this->x;
 return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(pb);                                                                            The program crashes in the assigment of this->x. pb is NULL.

Comment: Exactly. Which tells you that you are accessing `pb` in an invalid manner, because it is not pointing at a valid `B` object, so you can't cast the `A` pointer to a `B` pointer. You need to fix your `operator std::shared_ptr<B>()` to operate on a valid `B` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of `D::operator std::shared_ptr<B>()`, the use of `std::static_pointer_cast<B>(pb)` is **undefined behavior**, because `pb` does not point at an instance of `B` at that point, so it is illegal to cast the `A` pointer to a `B` pointer and access `B`'s members. `pb` is pointing at the instance of `A` created by `std::make_shared<A>()` in `D::operator std::shared_ptr<A>()`.  On the statement `pb = *this;`, you are discarding the `B` object you created and taking ownership of the `A` object that `*this` returns.

Thus, inside of `main()`, `pB` ends up pointing at an invalid `B` object and tries to destruct that object when `main()` exits, which is why you end up crashing the `A` destructor.

Had you used `dynamic_pointer_cast` instead of `static_pointer_cast` inside of `D::operator std::shared_ptr<B>()`, you would have ended up with a NULL pointer and likely crashed inside of `D::operator std::shared_ptr<B>()` when accessing `B::b`, instead of crashing in `main()`.

You need to fix your `operator std::shared_ptr<B>()` to operate on a valid instance of `B`, not on an instance of `A`.  For example:

```
operator std::shared_ptr<B>()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> pb = std::make_shared<B>();
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = *this;

    *static_pointer_cast<A>(pb) = *pa; // <-- copy pa->a to pb->a ...
    // or: simply do this instead:
    // pb->a = pa->a;

    pb->b = this->x;
    return pb;
}
```